# PRISM 6 Regions in WPF using DataTemplate/CustomControl

Tags: wpf, prism

What is the recommended way for defining regions in DataTemplates using PRISM 6?
If i define a region in a DataTemplate it will not be registered in the RegionManager...
I have same issue using a custom control with 3 ContentControls on it each defining a region. Can't find them in the regions collection in the RegionManager.

Comment: Post code which you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in Prism.  Here is your fix:

http://southworks.com/blog/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/

Comment: Ok, thanks! Already have seen your solution but was wondering if there is another solution already available with the PRISM 6 packages now. Seems thats not the case, so i will use your suggestion, thanks!